# Is there a way to make the children of a container resize uniformly to take up all available space (not flexbox!)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I've played around with and scoured the internet to see if either flex or grid will help with this problem to no avail. Here's the problem:

I have a container inside of which will only ever be one type of child (an square image). I would like every child to be the same size as all the other children, but I want the size of all the children to be set in order to take up all the available width and height of the container. As far as I know, flex cannot do this. If the flex-direction is row, for example, then setting the grow property on the children will only grow the children in rows where the full width isn't taken to fill the space. Grid views have a separate issue, whereas you cannot automate both the number of columns and the size of the columns (if using repeat(auto-fit), for example, you cannot use intrinsic or flexible sizes).

If it helps with a solution, this is for a react project and the styling is being defined as a style-component.

Does anybody have any creative solutions to this, or maybe a solution that I've overlooked in my search? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Would you post a sample html?

Comment: @TheKNVB the project is in react rather than, but it really is just a parent container with multiple children
```
<ItemStore>
                    <Item image={"mana_small.png"}></Item>
                    <Item image={"mana_small.png"}></Item>
                    <Item image={"mana_small.png"}></Item>
                    <Item image={"mana_small.png"}></Item>
                    <Item image={"mana_small.png"}></Item>
                </ItemStore>
```

Comment: are all tags derived from `div`?

Comment: @TheKNVB the container is, but the child is not. It's a button currently, but if it creates a solution I can make the child a div as well as it just needs to contain an image and be clickable.

Comment: are  all <item> in the same row?

Comment: @TheKNVB no, I need the children to resize and wrap. The end result would look like a grid of items. The items should be all the same size and there should be enough columns and rows to take up the full width and height of the parent container.

Comment: Have you tried  css `object-fit: cover` ?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Comment: @TheKNVB where would this go? inside a flexbox child or?

Comment: May be in `div`

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be to set a `padding-bottom` for each child with a percentage-based value that is equal to the `width`:

```css
.parent {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
}

.child {
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: calc(100% / 3 - 10px); /* 3 per row, accounting for margin */
  width: calc(100% / 3 - 10px); /* 3 per row, accounting for margin */
  background: red;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Just adjust the value `3` in both the `padding-bottom` and `width` to specify how many you want per row, and the `10px` to reflect the margin *in between* the elements.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, unfortunately this doesn't work as the images don't scale smaller if they don't fit in the available space and instead make the container so large most is not visible on even m y laptop screen.

Answer (score 0):

A table would do this for you automatically.  Set the table width to 100% (or however wide you want it to be).  ItemStore could declare a table and tbody, and then in each of the tbody's tr's tds you could stick an item image.

Comment: Yes but then I'd have to statically set number of rows and number of columns. I want that to be set automatically to fill the parent container.

Comment: You'll need to do it with JavaScript.  There is no way to tell the browser to just make everything fit.  If all your stuff is in one element like a div, you can querySelectorAll it and loop over stuff and adjust the size to fit the screen.  Are you aware of the zoom css property?  That might be what you want here.  You could adjust the zoom on the containing element so that it always fits your screen.  You'd do that with JavaScript after it has rendered.  You could just adjust the zoom on the container element rather than each individual element.